# How to fix F grade for YSlow with 3rd party JavaScripts?

Tags: javascript, performance, yslow

I get the following F grade:

`Grade F on Add Expires headers
There are 6 static components without a far-future expiration date.
(2016/10/13) https://cjs.ptengine.com/pta_en.js
(2016/10/14) https://cjs.ptengine.com/3a2dc781.js
(2016/10/14) https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?...
(2016/10/14) https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
(2016/10/14) https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js
(no expires) https://preprod.be-novative.com/feed/`

Is there a recommended way in 2016 to improve these?

Comment: what does it matter? yahoo believes everything should never expire, other people believe that just maybe it'd be a good thing to expire in the "near" future in case new versions are rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better ways of solving this is to download the JS file to a location that can set cache headers (for example `Cache-Control: max-age=2419200`). This must be updated regularly.